# Upper hemicontinuity of a correspondence

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, continuity

I would like to know whether the following correspondence is upper hemicontinuous:

$$
C(x)=\begin{cases}
1, & (f(x)>0) \\
[0,1], & (f(x)=0) \\
0, & (f(x) < 0)
\end{cases},
$$

whenever $f$ is continuous. If yes, I'd appreciate a proof. If not, intuition about why not would be welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: If $C(x)$ is a function then what is the $[0,1]$ meaning?

Comment: It is not a function but a correspondence (a set-valued function).

Answer (score 0):

Proof.

Let $\{x_m\} \rightarrow x$ be any convergent sequence and $\{y_m \in C(x_m)\} \rightarrow y$. (If $\{y_m \in C(x_m)\}$ does not converge, we need not prove anything about it.) We must prove that $y \in C(x)$ to satisfy the definition of upper hemicontinuity.

Either (i) there exists some positive integer $N$ such that for all integers $n > N$, $f(x_n) = 0$, or (ii) for every positive integer $N$ there exists an integer $n > N$ such that $f(x_n) \not = 0$.

Suppose (i), then for every $n > N, C(x_n) = [0,1]$, and, by the continuity of $f$, $f(x) = 0$, hence $C(x) = [0,1]$. As $y_m \in C(x_m)$ and $C(x_n) = [0,1]$ for all $n > N$, it must be that $y \in [0,1]$, because $y_m \in [0,1]$ and $[0,1]$ is closed (i.e., contains its limit points). Hence $y \in C(x)$.

Suppose (ii), and let $a \in (0,1)$. For every $N$, there exists some $n > N$ such that $f(x_n) \not = 0 \implies C(x_n) \in \{0,1\} \implies |y_n - a| \geq \min \{a,1-a\}$. Thus, $\{y_m\} \not \rightarrow a$. Hence $y$ must be either 0 or 1. Without loss of generality, suppose y = 1. Then for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an integer $N_\epsilon$ such that for all integers $n > N_\epsilon$, $|y_n - 1| < \epsilon $. Consider $\epsilon = 1/2$. For all $n > N_{1/2}$ $|y_n - 1| < 1/2 \implies f(x_n) \geq 0$. Then, by the continuinty of $f, f(x) \geq 0$, which implies that $y = 1 \in C(x)$.

QED